# How can I throw an exception within ListeningExecutorService?

Tags: guava, threadpoolexecutor

I used ListeningExecutorService of guava in my project, got confused about the exception handling.

I used a thread pool, submit a task to it, and set a timeout to the listenableFuture, and add a callback to it.

```
 final ListeningExecutorService threadPool = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());



 Futures.addCallback(listenableFuture, new FutureCallback<**>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@Nullable ** data) {
            xxxxxxx;
        }

        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            xxxxxxxxxx;
            if (t instanceof CancellationException) {
                throw new QueryException("yyyy");
            } else {
                throw new QueryException("zzzzz");
            }
        }
    });
```

I can't catch the exception inside the callback. So I use another ListenableFuture to get the exception

```
 ListenableFuture allFutures = Futures.allAsList(allFuturesList);
        try {
            allFutures.get();
        } catch (CancellationException ce) {
            throw new QueryException("");
        } catch (InterruptedException t) {
            throw new QueryException("");
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            Throwable t = e.getCause();
            if (t instanceof QueryException)
                throw (QueryException) t;
            else
                throw new QueryException();
        } catch (QueryException qe) {
            throw qe;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new QueryException();
        } finally {
        }
```

But I when the callback throw a QueryException, the allFutures can't catch it, allFutures can only catch a CancellationException without the detail error message.

How can I get my detail error message?

Answer (score 2):

## `Futures.allAsList` doesn't do what you expect it to do

From the Javadoc: (emphasis is from me)

> Canceling this future will attempt to cancel all the component futures, and **if any of the provided futures** fails or **is canceled, this one is, too**.

What you should probably do is create your own aggregating future. You can base your code on Guava's own internal mechanism. See [the source code](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/CollectionFuture.java) for more info.

Anyways, do **not** throw exceptions in your `FutureCallback::onFailure` method.

Comment: I want to shutdown the whole threadpool when any Future fails and get specific execution context to show to user. Is it possible to do it with ListeningExecutorService?

Comment: @lulijun Let me rephrase: you want to execute code asynchronously, then aggregate all the results (whether failed or successful) into one object that you can present to your customer, right?

Comment: Yes, when any of the thread fail, I will not present the aggregated result, I will present a message with detail error.

Comment: @lulijun I updated my post. Though I recommend using Java 8's `CompletableFuture` instead of Guava's `ListenableFuture`.